# Return value of Queries\Shop::getByDomain() must implement interface ShopModel or be null, instance of Collection returned

Tags: php, oop, shopify

Return value of Osiset\ShopifyApp\Storage\Queries\Shop::getByDomain() must implement interface Osiset\ShopifyApp\Contracts\ShopModel or be null, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection returned

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get the most useful answer, you'll want to post a bit more context. For example: What are you trying to do? And where is this exception being thrown? Is it in a controller? Is it in a service? Somewhere else? (Include the name of the file and the line number.) Try to also show some of the code that surrounds the line that's showing the error. Include the whole surrounding function if that's possible. With that information, hopefully you will get some useful tips from a Laravel or Shopify person. (I am, sadly, not such a person at the moment.) Good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.